# Creating a DJVU file from scanned BMPs

Tags: djvu

Recently I have been scanning some of my hand written notes.  Each page ends up as a .bmp file (300 DPI A4).  I wish to combine/compress these too a DJVU file for easy reading.

Hence,

- Does anyone know of any programs/utilities for OS X/Linux that can do this.
- If so, what settings can be considered optimal (lined paper, some coloured ink used).
- Are there any practical means of tagging pages/regions (to create an outline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some help available here:
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Creating_a_DjVu_file

The package for doing it is DjVuLibre, which has a utility to create a DJVU file from a TIFF or PBM file. If you need something to easily convert your BMPs to TIFFs, try ImageMagick.

Ad far as outline tagging, I'm entirely lost on how you'd do that.

Answer (score 1):

Any2Djvu is a good utility :
[Any2Djvu](http://any2djvu.djvuzone.org/)

If you want to convert into pdf , ImageMagick is a good one. ( It's mainly an image processing utility . )
[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

For more info , go to [here](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Help:DjVu_files#Images_directly_to_DjVu)